# What are JS Callbacks/Hooks (Meteor: Aldeed Autoform)?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've been reading about some documentation on Callbacks and Hooks for a meteor application I'm making, which uses the Aldeed Autoform package. I was told hooks would be helpful to me in something that I wanted to do, but I cant actually figure out what Callbacks and Hooks are. An explanation or even a link to a site that explains it would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A callback is a function that is passed as a parameter to another function:

```
// Function that accepts a callback
function greet(name, callback) {
    var greeting = 'Hello ' + name + '!';
    callback(greeting);
};

// Call greet function with name, and anonymous function 
greet('Dave', function(greeting) {
    alert(greeting); // 'Hello Dave!'
});
```

It's particularly useful when you want to do something asynchronous, where you don't know how long the process will take, or when it will be completed e.g an AJAX request. You can wrap up the logic you want to be completed after the request has come back in a function, e.g updating the DOM, and it will be executed whenever it needs to be.